# Ionic/Angular router doesn't redirect properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a simple ionic app, and meanwhile coding I have faced a problem in the form that the router works, when I try to access a page directly from the url(Putting the url in the browser), it redirects me to a blank url(http://localhost:8100/ to be more specific), and it should work reversely.

Hope you can help me, I tried hardly but I can't see the error. Here is the code:

food-list.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FoodListPage } from './food-list.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children : [
      {
        path : '',
        component : FoodListPage
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        loadChildren : () => import('./food-detail/food-detail.module').then( m => m.FoodDetailPageModule),
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class FoodListPageRoutingModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'food-list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./food-list/food-list.module').then( m => m.FoodListPageModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/food-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I already tried removing the slash from the redirect route, and nothing, if you need more of the code, please, let me know, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I've also never managed to get route parameters to work when they have no other static path, e.g `{path:':my_param'}`

If possible I would recommend adding an intermediate path name, e.g.

```
{
        path: 'detail/:id',
        loadChildren : () => import('./food-detail/food-detail.module').then( m => m.FoodDetailPageModule),
      }
```

and updating your other routing to include the `detail/` prefix.

You may also have additional issues when deploying to a live server, despite the multiple paths you have there is still only 1 main file that is the entry-point for the server (your index.html file, all routes are essentially artificial), so depending on your hosting choice you should also make sure you follow their guidance to configure for server-side apps (common hosts like firebase and netlify make this very easy to do).

Comment: After a few attemps to resolve it, I realized that there was a double import error, and that's why it wasn't working, also, I learn some things for your answer, thanks for your help

Comment: Most welcome, I'm glad you managed to fix it in the end. I also retried on one of my own projects with a single parameterised route like in your example and was happy to see it work (angular is always slowly improving), so good that I could learn something also